# How can I show an image in sweet alert that I want to upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader, sweetalert

I have the following code not working. I want the image to appear in a swal (Sweet Alert) when the input is changed, but I don't know what's not working. I get the following error on console:

`Failed to execute'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not type 'Blob'`

**INPUT**

```
<input id="input" type="file" style="display:none;" onchange="muda()">
```

**Script**

```
<script>
            function muda(){
                var thefile = document.getElementById('input');
                var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(){
                        var imagem = reader.result;
                    }
                        if(thefile){
                            reader.readAsDataURL(thefile);
                        }
                swal({
                  title: "Esta é a imagem que pretende inserir?",
                  text: "<img src='"+imagem+"' style='width:150px;'>",
                  html:true,
                });
            }
        </script>
```

***UPDATE***

With adaneo response, I managed to read the file name adding `.files[0];` but I don't know how to get the image path now, I tried to put a variable named image as you can see in the code but it turns `undefined`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument you're passing in, `thefile`, is a DOM element, not a file.

You want to pass the file, not the entire element

```
var thefile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
```

That selects the first *(and only, as it doesn't have "multiple" set)* file and passes it to the FileReader

`reader.onloadend` is asynchronous, you have to put your swal() function inside the callback

Here's another way to do this, without the inline javascript

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var thefile = this.files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    swal({
        title: "Esta é a imagem que pretende inserir?",
        text: "<img src='" + reader.result + "' style='width:150px;'>",
        html: true,
    });
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(thefile);
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, now I have another problem, check the update

Comment: Well, `reader.onloadend` is **asynchronous**, you have to put your `swal()` function inside the callback

Answer (score 3):

```
<div onclick="imgClick(this)">
   <img src="image/img1.jpg" width="150px">

</div>

<script>
function imgClick(e){
    var src = $(e).find('img').attr('src');
    swal({
           title: "Hello World",
           text: "<img src='"+src+"' style='width:150px;'>",
           content:true,
        });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

along with @adeneo reply, I would like to add more about swal. As per the latest swal documentation, it should be as follows

```
swal({
  title: '<strong>HTML <u>example</u></strong>',
  type: 'info',
  html:
    'You can use <b>bold text</b>, ' +
    '<a href="//github.com">links</a> ' +
    'and other HTML tags',
});
```

you can put anything in the html tag of course.